# How do I fix a NotSerializable exception

Tags: java, serialization, rmi

I have a program called Agent that launches a thread called BeaconSender:

```
    public class BeaconSender extends Thread {

    private Beacon beacon;
    private String managerAddress;
    public BeaconSender(Beacon b, String host){beacon = new Beacon(b); managerAddress = 
    host;}

    public void run(){
        while(true){
            try{
                BeaconListener access = (BeaconListener) 
                Naming.lookup("rmi://"+managerAddress+":1900"+"/BeaconListener");
                access.deposit(beacon);
                System.err.println("Sent beacon to manager");
            }catch(Exception e){
                System.err.println("BeaconSender exception :" + e.toString());
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            try {
                Thread.sleep(1000);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Which is basically sending a Beacon object periodically to a BeaconListener which is supposed to take the beacon and add it's information to a list of Beacons in a class called Manager.

And the Beacon Class is:

```
    public class Beacon {
    private int ID; //Randomly generated at start up
    private LocalTime startUpTime; //When this client starts
    private String cmdAgentID; //The registry string of CmdAgent
    private String agentAddress; //The address of the agent

    Beacon(Beacon b){
        this.ID = b.ID;
        this.startUpTime = b.startUpTime;
        this.cmdAgentID = b.cmdAgentID;
        this.agentAddress = b.agentAddress;
    }
    Beacon(String cmdAgentID, String agentAddress){
        Random random = new Random();
        int low = 1024;
        int high = 65535;
        ID = random.nextInt(high-low)+low;
        startUpTime = LocalTime.now();
        this.cmdAgentID = cmdAgentID;
        this.agentAddress = agentAddress;
    }

    public int getBeaconID(){return ID;}
    public void setBeaconID(int idnum){ID = idnum;}
    public void setStartUpTime(LocalTime newTime){this.startUpTime = newTime;}
    public LocalTime getStartUpTime(){return startUpTime;}
    public void setCmdAgentID(String agent){this.cmdAgentID = agent;}
    public String getCmdAgentID(){return cmdAgentID;}
    public String getHost() {return agentAddress;}
}
```

And the errors I am getting are:

```
BeaconSender exception :java.rmi.MarshalException: error marshalling arguments; nested exception is: 
    java.io.NotSerializableException: agent.Beacon
    java.rmi.MarshalException: error marshalling arguments; nested exception is: 
    java.io.NotSerializableException: agent.Beacon
    at java.rmi/sun.rmi.server.UnicastRef.invoke(UnicastRef.java:160)
    at java.rmi/java.rmi.server.RemoteObjectInvocationHandler.invokeRemoteMethod(RemoteObjectInvocationHandler.java:217)
    at java.rmi/java.rmi.server.RemoteObjectInvocationHandler.invoke(RemoteObjectInvocationHandler.java:162)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy1.deposit(Unknown Source)
    at agent.BeaconSender.run(BeaconSender.java:19)
Caused by: java.io.NotSerializableException: agent.Beacon
    at java.base/java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1185)
    at java.base/java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:349)
    at java.rmi/sun.rmi.server.UnicastRef.marshalValue(UnicastRef.java:293)
    at java.rmi/sun.rmi.server.UnicastRef.invoke(UnicastRef.java:155)
    ... 4 more
```

I tried implementing Serializable in each class separately and then both and I still kept getting errors. I am not really sure what is causing java to kick these errors out when "access.deposit(beacon)". I understand serializable has something to do with version control, but I am not sure if my program is in a framework that works with the Serializable interface or I am just missing something in the Manager and the Agent that is keeping me from getting this to work.

Comment: Adding `implements Serializable` to your Beacon class should be sufficient.

Comment: I tried that and still got errors.

Comment: I was wrong, it worked, but now it is getting errors in my Manager program for java.io.EOFException.

Comment: You have a loop that reads from the RMI service forever, even after the server side has terminated the connection.  An EOFException is expected, because you have literally reached the end of the data stream.

Comment: Yep, that was the fix. Also had to Serialize the objects that were being passed over the RMI interface

Comment: You mean make them `implements Serializable`. It isn't the same thing. Serialization is the process that failed because they weren't `Serializable`.